# How do I build emacs from sources on macOS Catalina Version 10.15.4

Tags: compilation, source

I typically run gnuemacs using MacPorts. However, I have a friend who does not have admin on his managed mac, so I want to build for him a full release of emacs that will run out of his home directory. He does not have admin rights.

I tried downloading the sources for all of these versions:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 xf  staff  20403483 Feb 17  2005 emacs-21.4a.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 xf  staff  39587396 Sep  5  2008 emacs-22.3.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 xf  staff  47721193 Jan 28  2012 emacs-23.4.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 xf  staff  39759804 Apr 10  2015 emacs-24.5.tar.xz
-rw-r--r--  1 xf  staff  44415140 Aug 28  2019 emacs-26.3.tar.xz
```

None of them build properly. I always end up with some kind of `Killed` error, like:

```
emacs-26.3 % make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C lib all
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C lib-src all
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C src VCSWITNESS='' all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C ../admin/charsets all
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C ../admin/unidata charscript.el
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `charscript.el'.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C ../admin/unidata all EMACS="../../src/bootstrap-emacs"
  ELC      uvs.elc
/bin/sh: line 1: 37172 Killed: 9               "../../src/bootstrap-emacs" -batch --no-site-file --no-site-lisp -f batch-byte-compile uvs.el
make[2]: *** [uvs.elc] Error 137
make[1]: *** [../lisp/international/charprop.el] Error 2
make: *** [src] Error 2
emacs-26.3 %
```

So I tried using brew. It built emacs, but I get the same problem:

```
% brew/bin/emacs
zsh: killed     brew/bin/emacs %
```

So what's the proper way to build this?

Comment: Wild guess: increase your stack limit using `ulimit -s`

Answer (score 1):

I build emacs from [Github source](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs).

```
autogen.sh
./configure
make 
make install
```

That compile without any error.

The file [INSTALL](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/INSTALL) provides more details on how to build and install Emacs.

[image: capture of emacs about]

Comment: Building Emacs on macOS has several issues. For instance using `gcc` causes problems. Usually, the Apple's `clang` should be used. Building with NS support is likely to cause `AppKit/AppKit.h not found` error too.

Comment: Thanks, @Romario. If you could post the dependencies, I can accept your answer.

Comment: strange, the only dependency I have to use is makeinfo, texinfo and gnutls

Comment: @vy32 Before Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion), building Emacs on 10.6 and 10.5 was a breeze because the `CoreFoundation`, `AppKit`, etc  were working with the Emacs' build script out of the box and the X Window Framework came built in. On newer versions of macOS, first try building a headless Emacs i.e. (assuming your default CC is GCC) `CC=/usr/bin/clang ./configure --without-ns --without-x --with-gnutls=no` then try with the NS support.

Comment: I actually don’t want NS support! I want just terminal mode. Very old school...

Comment: autogen.sh "should be needed only if you edit files like 'configure.ac' that
specify Emacs's autobuild procedure". Quote from the source README file.